Asciidoc images and includes, I need some help on this
I have the following situation. In my team we write everything in ADOC/Markdown and publish them to our internal Gitlab.  But the company took the decision to use Confluence as our single source of trust for documentation.
Thus, we were asked to create a Gitlab pipeline using Maven to publish our documentation to Confluence.
Our structure is:
.
├── docs
│   ├── images
│   ├── Topic A top file.adoc
│   ├── Topic A subdirectory
│   ├── Topic B top file.adoc
│   ├── Topic B subdirectory
│

So effectively we have a top-level document for every topic we document (for example "MySQL Deployment and configuration with Ansible" and then a subdirectory with documents that we include at the top-level one.
Our problem is that Maven pipeline fails when we have any image: statement! Because Maven cannot understand that this structure and thus, it assumes that each adoc is independent.
Is there any way to use an adoc directive in the form of if dir=subdir the images_dir=../images else images ?

How are you getting the listing?  is that a file or stored in a variable?  Code example?
